# Passing keyword arguments to clojurescript functions from javascript

Tags: clojurescript

It's possible to invoke a clojurescript function from javascript, for example:

```
cljs.core.keyword("foobar")
```

returns the `:foobar` keyword, positional arguments work as you would expect. I'm trying to invoke js->clj with the `:keywordize-keys` argument but so far I haven't been successful. I've tried:

```
cljs.core.js__GT_clj({'foo': 42}, {'keywordize-keys': true})

// and

var k = cljs.core.keyword('keywordize-keys')
cljs.core.js__GT_clj({'foo': 42}, {k: true})
```

but neither seem to work as I had hoped. In general how do you specify keyword arguments when calling from js into cljs?

Comment: I'm usually going the other way, using clj->js but there appears to be a js->clj that might do the trick: Check out http://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/09/12/clojurescript-javascript-interop/

Answer (score 2):

In cljs you call the function like this:

```
(js->clj #js {"foo" 42} :keywordize-keys true)
```

And the corresponding js code:

```
var k = cljs.core.keyword('keywordize-keys')
cljs.core.js__GT_clj({'foo': 42}, k, true)
```